# VB.NET - Customizing Listview/Listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

So there are a few Answered questions but I still dont really understand what i'm meant to do. Like how can I basically make my Listview very customized.

What im trying to get it to look like is:

[image: 1]

As you can see it's HEAVILLY customized - I made this in Photoshop if you were wondering and I dont EXACTLY need the Scrollbar customized or that Hover-Highlight effect as of right now but in the Future a way to do it would be needed.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

EDIT: The closest thing I can get it to is:
[image: 2]
But theres a "FEW" issues - I cant get the Text alignment/position to look right as I need to put 2 spaces before the Text for it to actually look decent which "MIGHT" give issues for me in the future when trying to get actions on click. Next, There's for some reason no option to using Borders/Grids which remove the ability to do that slightly darker gray border around the Boxes in the first image. Any ideas guys?

(What I used to make it like this is: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599375-ListBox-with-custom-items-(colors-images-text-alignment))

Edit 2: Re-Edit: Ok I tought I got the Highlight Color sorted but it doesnt seem like it as im using FillRectangle but no matter how I put the Bounds (Which are correct) it seems to leave an extra like 1px border of White for about 1-2 seconds before its refreshed and gone. Anyway to fix this?

Edit 3: The http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599375-ListBox-with-custom-items-(colors-images-text-alignment) ListBox I was using where I "ALMOST" got it done wont work for me due to it just not being stable - If I edit anything after making the ColorListBox in the Design mode it will just not work and give me errors which is annoying. It also has the "SelectedItem" parameter as no longer an Object which ruins half of my code. Other then that if those 2 are fixable I guess it would work but I have no idea how to fix it :(

So I reverted to a VERY basic ListBox for now with just text until you guys can help find a way to customize it like the first image above.

Comment: You could just add an empty subItem and set the column width of the listview  accordingly .. `ListView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 5` or whatever value suits you

Comment: As far as the refresh goes, in the sub that causes the refresh, just add `listview1.SuspendLayout` at the beginning of the sub, and at the end, add `listview1.ResumeLayout` - replacing `listview1` with the name of your ListView of course

Comment: @DavidWilson For the first comment you made im assuming your on about adding an image to a Non Custom Listview right? Also for the second comment would that fix this issue: https://i.gyazo.com/e788a32b9cd052be1b9685cf42f22556.gif

Comment: @DavidWilson Oh nevermind - I understand what you saying- The first comment is about the Spacing Issue - Looks good I might give it a go. But for the Second comment it didnt seem to work D: Eitherway I decided to give up on using it as its really buggy everytime I change something in the Designer it will add "Pragma." to the start of the ColorBox thing in the Designer.vb so its too annoying to work with. Anyway I could do this standalone or something?

Comment: A ListView would not be my first (or even last) choice for this.  You might be able to get most of what you want [just using a Button](http://i.imgur.com/cDfS1k8.jpg).  To get real fancy, [build a UserControl](http://i.imgur.com/lSydwkb.jpg) or custom control on an AutoScroll panel which will allow you to do whatever you want.  Your images dont make what you are describing very obvious because of different OS's, themes and visual styles.  Hard to tell what is applied by the OS and what is special.

Comment: Apologies @ShinyMK , I could have sworn that i had replied to your question about clarifying my answer.

Comment: Ooops- nerver a good idea to edit the designer.vb file directly :)

Comment: @Plutonix I really dont think using buttons would be a good choice because I use a Listbox1.ToArray(<list>) to add the Channels Title to it. I decided aswell not to use a Listview and started with a Listbox but how can I add images to it and customize it to look like the Image I posted? Not sure what you mean by the OS etc so...

Comment: You are commingling the data layer with the UI layer.  A plain button *can* work for the user display, but ideally a subclassed one or a UserControl so you can fine tune it for things like a Selected and Hot (MousrHover) states as in the second image as well as provide a concrete link to the data elements.  I mentioned a button for its simplicity

Comment: @Plutonix Yes I understand its possible but like, How would I convert a List with the Channel Title to a bunch of buttons? Like I just dont see that happening.

Comment: `convert a List with the Channel Title to a bunch of buttons` You dont.  The UI is just how code interacts with users: display stuff we need users to see, then get input from them.  It is suboptimal for storing data.  You'd create `n` number of controls *from* the list. The only visual element in the list is the Name of the channel, it might also need an ID to link that button to a specific channel (like index in the list).

Comment: @Plutonix I see but I generally dont like the idea of using buttons. Is there any way I could just use a Listview? I got it looking pretty similar the only issue im having is converting Image urls from Channel.Poster (List) to an ImageList and then linking them in the same order.

Comment: You have to handle the paint event of your list view to get the customization you are trying to achieve. And what you describe would be a long tutorial. Have you tried using WPF?

Comment: Just use a ListView, change the View property to Tile.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not at all clear what you want exactly. `Like how can I basically make my Listview very customized` is vague and very broad (and why you didn't get an answer you liked).

A picture is nice, but *words* describing the desired appearance would have been better. Given a picture to scrutinize, there is no way to know what is Important and what is just there...because. I assume every detail is important based on `very customized`.   Additionally:

- **`Listview/Listbox`** Pick one: they are very different controls.
- The little 2 pixel margin between items would be very problematic for a `ListView`, so I scratched the LV<sup>1</sup>.
- Why are all the items gray in the first image?  That typically indicates disabled, so can items be disabled (such as when there is no program data for a given channel)?
- What does the gray box on "FOX" represent?  Is it the selected item?  Is it the HotLight/MouseHover item?  `ListBox`/`ListView` items do not normally light up when the mouse passes over (the LV can when `HotTracking` is true, but thats only when the mouse is over the `Item` not subitem(s)).
- Is the darker gray for that box rectangle an absolute color?  The `HotLight` and `Selected` coloring is usually handled by the OS (==Operating System) respecting the theme and color choices of the user.  Is this gadget supposed to ignore those, or is your theme using some shade of gray for Highlight ?

I measured the elements in the first image carefully to get some metrics, then made guesses on the answers to the above.

### No Code Solution

**Use a Button.**  Since the user will presumably click one of these to select a desired channel, a `Button` makes more sense than a `ListView` (much more).  You can display an image on a `Button` along with text, and use the `FlatAppearance` properties to style it how you want.  Use the `Tag` to track the channel ID or the index of the related channel in the collection.

Finally, use the `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events to manipulate `FlatAppearance.BorderSize` and `FlatAppearance.BorderColor` to get very close to the first image in the question:

[image]

They reside in an scrolling `Panel`. The panel width is just a bit wider than the control to avoid the horizontal scrollbar.  As for the buttons, the `HotLight` border (???) is around the entire control rather than just the text.  Not what your picture shows you want, but on the other hand, there is nothing involved beyond some standard properties and a little event handling code (5-6 lines).

---

### Image ListBox

An ownerdraw ListBox will get you a bit closer to what you want, but ultimately this just makes it look like a `ListBox` that has `Buttons` in it.

**Place a ListBox on the form**, and set these properties:
 - DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed
 - IntegralHeight = False
 - Itemheight = 64 (this is based on the fact that the images are 60x60 in the first image)
 - Set the BackColor to `ControlLight` or `{233,233,233}` for that exact shade of gray as desired.

As mentioned, `ListBox` items do not normally light up when the mouse is over them, so we need some code to track that (like a `Button`):

```
Private mouseItem As Int32 = -1
Private Sub lbChannels_MouseMove(sender As Object,
                                 e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lbChannels.MouseMove

    Dim ndx = lbChannels.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)
    ' test to avoid millions of paints
    If ndx <> mouseItem Then
        If mouseItem <> -1 Then
            ' invalidate/redraw the OLD itemrect 
            lbChannels.Invalidate(lbChannels.GetItemRectangle(mouseItem))
        End If
        mouseItem = ndx
        ' invalidate/redraw the NEW itemrect 
        lbChannels.Invalidate(lbChannels.GetItemRectangle(mouseItem))
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub lbChannels_MouseLeave(sender As Object,
                                  e As EventArgs) Handles lbChannels.MouseLeave
    If mouseItem <> -1 Then
        ' get rect for what wont be the hot item in a tick
        Dim rect = lbChannels.GetItemRectangle(mouseItem)
        'lbChannels.Invalidate()
        mouseItem = -1              ' no longer Hot
        lbChannels.Invalidate(rect)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Updated** to minimize flickering by redrawing just the items which changed.

I did not use the `MouseHover` event because that fires later, resulting the small (but no where near a second) delay mentioned.  `MouseMove` also makes it easier to get the mouse location.

**IImageItem**

Based on comments, you want to auto-generate items based on some other data in the app.  Rather than assume what that class looks like and to make this easy  to implement and applicable to *any* class, this will use an interface:

```
Public Interface IImageItem
    Property ID As String      ' ???
    Property ItemImage As Image
    Property Text As String
End Interface
```

The draw code will *require that interface be implemented* so it can use those properties to draw your items.  `Id` is an extra one to allow a way to link which `ListBox` item is selected or clicked from the collection (only needed if you add items to the `ListBox` -- not recommended). It could be extended to include an `Enabled` property to draw those differently, if needed. You'd implement this interface on your collection items class thusly:

```
Public Class ChannelItem
    Implements IImageItem

    Public Property ItemImage As Image Implements IImageItem.ItemImage
    Public Property Text As String Implements IImageItem.Text
    Public Property ID As String Implements IImageItem.ID
    ' + your existing properties

    Public Sub New(txt As String, img As Image, key As String)
        Text = txt
        ItemImage = img
        ID = key
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
```

**Note:** `ChannelItem` is *my* demo version of whatever class you are using to track the channels.  Just type `Implements IImageItem` on your class, press enter and the IDE will add the properties, set them before adding items to your collection.

**DrawItem Code**

```
Private Sub lbChannels_DrawItem(sender As Object,
                                e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles lbChannels.DrawItem
    Dim lb As ListBox = lbChannels
    If e.Index < 0 Then
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "", lb.Font, e.Bounds, lb.ForeColor)
        Return
    End If

    Dim iItem As IImageItem
    If TypeOf (lb.Items(e.Index)) Is IImageItem Then
        iItem = DirectCast(lb.Items(e.Index), IImageItem)
    Else
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, lb.Items(e.Index).ToString,
                              lb.Font, e.Bounds, lb.ForeColor)
        Return
    End If

    Dim imgRect As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty
    Dim txtRect As Rectangle

    ' calc 
    If iItem.ItemImage IsNot Nothing Then
        imgRect = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 1,
                                 iItem.ItemImage.Width + 2, iItem.ItemImage.Height + 2)
    End If

    ' GetTextExtent
    Dim sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText("   " & iItem.Text, lb.Font)
    txtRect = New Rectangle(iItem.ItemImage.Width + 4, e.Bounds.Y + 1,
                         (e.Bounds.Width - iItem.ItemImage.Width) - 8,
                          e.Bounds.Height - 2)

    ' Draw Big Box around the text portion
    If e.Index = mouseItem Then
        Using pR As New Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark, 2), 
                brB As New SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pR, txtRect)
            txtRect.Inflate(-1, -1)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brB, txtRect)
        End Using
    ElseIf (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)) Then
        ' ToDo: modify for whatever is desired for the selected item
        '        this is a guess/example
        Using pR As New Pen(SystemColors.Highlight, 2), 
                       brB As New SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pR, txtRect)
            txtRect.Inflate(-1, -1)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brB, txtRect)
        End Using
    Else
       ' could use a channel specific color for each BG
       ' just extend IImageItem
        e.DrawBackground()
    End If

    If iItem.ItemImage IsNot Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(iItem.ItemImage, imgRect)
    End If

    ' recalc TR for where the text really goes
    txtRect = New Rectangle(iItem.ItemImage.Width + 4, e.Bounds.Y + 1,
                         sz.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Height - 0)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, iItem.Text, lb.Font, txtRect, lb.ForeColor)
End Sub
```

Again, it is not clear whether the darker gray box for "FOX" represents the SelectedItem`,`HotLight`/Hover item or even disabled.  The code shows how/where to box the text for the first 2 cases.  Modify as needed.

**Usage**

```
' a collection of ChannelItem objects (which implement IImageItem)
Dim channels As New List(Of ChannelItem)

' my fake data
channels.Add(New ChannelItem("More 4", My.Resources.SO_LVImg01, "M4"))
channels.Add(New ChannelItem("Channel 4", My.Resources.SO_LVImg02, "4"))
channels.Add(New ChannelItem("RTE One", My.Resources.SO_LVImg03, "RET1"))
channels.Add(New ChannelItem("FOX", My.Resources.SO_LVImg04, "Fox"))
...
```

It is all pretty straightforward, just substitute your class for `ChannelItem` (it must implement `IImageItem`).  Rather than copy items into the items collection, you can use that collection as the `DataSource`:

```
lbChannels.DataSource = channels
```

`SelectedValue` will be a `ChannelItem` object boxed as `System.Object`, cast it back to get at ***all*** the related data such as a URL or *Now Playing* text.

The result:

[image][image]

In this case, the selected item has a `SystemColor.Hightlight` box (blue in my case), and the item the mouse is over has a gray box.  There even appears to be the little 2px gap between each item as in the original image.  This is the result of the image height being a bit less than the `ItemHeight` used.

Putting a border on the things would elide the need to do mouse over highlighting.

---

### UserControl

If you want (nearly) total control over how these pseudo buttons appear, you should probably build a `UserControl`. Using a `Label` and `PictureBox` and just the normal events you could get it to do almost anything you want.  You can slap one together in about 20 mins:

[image]

The `Channel` UserControls are contained in an autoscrolling `Panel`.  They are basically a custom button, but allows you a great deal of control over the layout, behavior and appearance.  Best of all, each would have its own distinct `Click` event.

---

<sup>1</sup> The *reason* there are no gaps between items in the LV or LB is to make it easier for users to select an item.  A gutter or gap opens the chance that the user could click there and get no result.  Or depending on the implementation, your code would crash using a bad index.